# Is this "approved" online loan a scam? I was asked for my user name and password

Tags: loans, banking, scams

I'm pretty sure what the answer is, but I don't want my desperation to cloud my judgment.

I was approved for a loan after giving my bank account and routing info. They requested to verify the account was mine, and asked me to submit my online user name and password. Just want to make sure that this IS a scam!

Comment: Desperation/fear is often bad council when making financial decisions.  Prior to doing anything please seek the advice of someone you trust.

Comment: What is the name/website of the place where you applied for the loan?

Answer (score 10):

A legitimate bank giving you a loan would never ask for your username and password to another bank.

Yes, it is a scam.

In the future: If you think it is a scam, it probably is.

Comment: Some lending sites as well as online budgeting sites will have you log on to your bank through their site however.  So in a way they are asking for your username and password.

Comment: A legitimate bank would never ask you for your password, period.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if someone asks you to verbally reveal a password that you normally type on a keyboard and use to log in via computer, then it is a scam.